# Programatically add a user to people web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, web-part, pnp-provision

I'm trying to programatically(c#) add a user to a sharepoint People web part on a modern page but with no success.

I try to set the "persons"-property the same way it looks after adding a person manually.

```
    var peopleComp = page.InstantiateDefaultWebPart(DefaultClientSideWebParts.People);

    dynamic json = JObject.Parse(peopleComp.PropertiesJson.ToString());

    json["persons"] = "[{\"id\":\"i:0#.f|membership|user@mail.com\",\"upn\":\"user@mail.com\",\"role\":\"IT\",\"department\":\"IT\",\"phone\":\"\",\"sip\":\"\"}]";

    page.AddControl(peopleComp);
    page.Save(model.Url);
```

I get no errors but the control is added with no user.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: If I try to set peopleComp["persons"] instead of propertiesJson the site presents a "load people" symbol when opening but never gets finnished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var peopleComp = page.InstantiateDefaultWebPart(DefaultClientSideWebParts.People);

if (peopleComp != null)
{
      peopleComp.Title = "people";
      peopleComp.PropertiesJson = "{'layout':1, 'persons':[{'id':'i:0#.f|membership|USERMAIL'}],'title':''}";

      page.AddControl(peopleComp);
}

page.Save(your site url)
```